# How to more quickly import a long list of global symbols from Fortran dylib into C?

Tags: c, fortran, language-interoperability

I am creating a C wrapper for an extensive Fortran library `algorithms` of which I am not the author.

This Fortran library is made up of multiple modules each containing many global subroutines and variables.  Although there are only a handful of user end functions I need, the library is such that it needs to be initialized to set technical parameters before its subroutines can be used. That requires C to be able to access global variables of the Fortran library.  Therefore, it seems I need to `extern "C"` all these subroutines and variables.

The author of the Fortran library did not use `iso_c_binding` but I am able to find all the names of these functions using `nm -g algorithms.a` or `nm -g algorithms.dylib`.  The list is very *very* long, and it is taking me forever to write:

```
extern "C" {
    int __algorithms_recurse_MOD_accuracy;
    int __algorithms_recurse_MOD_precision;
    int __algorithms_recurse_MOD_taracc;
    void __algorithms_recurse_MOD_optrecurse(int* x, int* y);
    // and so on and on...
}
```

Is there a better strategy than to do this manually?  (It's especially time consuming to find out exactly the return types of all these functions).

Comment: I don't think there is any.

Comment: I'd first write a wrapper layer in Fortran that provided a BIND(C) interface to the Fortran library, and then have your C wrapper interface with that.  This will avoid issues with different Fortran compilers using different name mangling conventions for module procedures.

Comment: But that is even more work at the beginning.

Comment: Where did you get `extern "C"`? Is this C++? C++ is not C, it is actually very different.